# CircleCI Grant Issue

Tags: circleci

I am trying to set up CircleCI and followed the Salesforce DX instructions carefully.

I believe I set up the Connected App correctly as I can test the grant from bash successfully:

```
$ sfdx auth:jwt:grant --clientid (MY CLIENT ID) --jwtkeyfile server.key --username (MY USER ID) --setdefaultdevhubusername
Successfully authorized (MY USER ID) with org ID 00Do0000000bXXXXXX
```

I also think I have set up the CircleCI environment variables correctly:

[image]

However when I run the project from CircleCI I get a grant error:

```
ERROR running force:auth:jwt:grant:  We encountered a JSON web token error, which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the error: user hasn't approved this consumer
```

[image]

Any ideas why the local grant test works but not from CircleCI?

Here is my yaml file:

```yaml
 version: 2
 
 general:
 
 jobs:
   build:
     machine: true
     working_directory: ~/ci_app
     environment:
       # from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_standalone.htm
       # and https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/manifest.json
       - DX_CLI_URL: https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz
     steps:
       - checkout
       - run:
           name: Download CLI
           command: |
             mkdir sfdx
             wget -qO- $DX_CLI_URL | tar xJ -C sfdx --strip-components 1
       - run:
           name: Install CLI
           command: |
             ./sfdx/install
             sfdx
             mkdir tmp
       - run:
           name: Create hub key
           command: |
             echo 'make hub key'
             #- mkdir keys
             #- echo $HUB_SERVER_KEY_HEX | xxd -r -ps >> keys/hub.key
             openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -base64 -K $DECRYPTION_KEY -iv $DECRYPTION_IV
             #- openssl rsa -in keys/hub.key -check -noout
       - run:
           name: Setup Org
           command: |
             echo 'Running tests'
             sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $HUB_CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile assets/server.key --username $HUB_SFDC_USER --setdefaultdevhubusername -a hub            
             sfdx force --help
             sfdx force:org:create -s -f ~/ci_app/config/project-scratch-def.json -a circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM --wait 2
             sfdx force:source:push -u circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM
       - run:
           name: Run Apex Tests
           command: |
             mkdir -p ~/junit
             sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -d ~/junit -r junit --wait 5
       - store_test_results:
           path: ~/junit
       - run:
           name: Delete Useless Scratch Org
           command: |
             sfdx force:org:delete -u circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM -p
```

Adding Connected App info:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the same user account locally and in CircleCI? What is the configuration for Preapproved Permission Sets and Profiles on your Connected App?

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this, David!  Yes, I am using the same account for local bash execution and the CircleCI environment variable.  I have added the profile of this user to the the Profiles section under the Manage button.  I will add screen snaps of all this in case you see something funny I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CircleCI environment has:

HUB_SFDX_USER

The yaml file has:

sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $HUB_CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile assets/server.key --username $HUB_SFDC_USER ...

:-)

Comment: Wow am I a dummy!  Thanks Felix I will give that a shot.

Comment: I've screwed up bigger things today. Setting up CI/CD is very error-prone, I speak from experience...

Comment: That was the issue, Felix.  1000 thanks!!  Dave